# Why don't some of Apple's sample code demos use storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Some of the complicated sample code I've seen doesn't use storyboards, for example the [TheElements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html) demo. I'm curious to know why the demo generates all the views programatically as opposed to using a nib file or storyboards. From my understanding storyboards seem to be the recommended practice of developing interfaces.

Thanks

Comment: Storyboards are **a** way of developing interfaces, however some complex or highly custom interfaces can only be created with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards are great when you want to create interfaces. The Apple sample code is about understanding what's going on, including understanding the interface. Interface Builder has a lot of options, so it's tough to see what has been changed from the defaults.

Even in some of the newer code samples, there are no `.xib` files and it makes grasping the logic easier. Of course, that doesn't mean that you should follow that example and use no IB files. But starting by learning the long way has advantages.

Answer (score 2):

TheElements is a very old sample project. If I remember correctly it was one of the first samples in the first version of the SDK in 2008. Interface Builder didn't exist yet (for iOS apps) and Storyboards have been only introduced in iOS 5. They probably didn't think it was worth updating and rewriting a lot of the code.